# Error in opening MS Word file

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to open a Word file but it is giving me an error:

[image: error image]

Is it possible to fix this error and open the file? I tried opening it in Word pad and it was able to show me few pages.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when a text zone (or other object) is anchored on the same line than an oMaths object (equations).
If you are using Office 2010, just [update to the last service pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2687455/description-of-office-2010-service-pack-2) (SP2 currently). Else, you can run Microsoft Fixit (more information about your issue and fixes [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2528942/you-receive-an-end-tag-error-when-you-open-a-docx-file-in-word-2007--2)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already have Office 2010 SP2, and Microsoft Fixit has been deprecated.